# I can't capture my screen

Tags: command-line, obs-studio

I have installed obs-studio in ubuntu 21.04 version. I have faced following problems:

1. Not screen capture, just black window
2. Terrible voice after finishing the record
3. Not able to uninstall after 2nd installing

I have used these codes:

```
  $ sudo apt-get remove obs-studio

  $ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove obs-studio 

  $ sudo apt-get purge obs-studio 

  $ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove obs-studio
```

Is there any ways to uninstall obs or to fix those problems?

Comment: Have you installed your gpu drivers?

Comment: How did you install OBS-Studio? Also note that Ubuntu 21.04 uses wayland by default. You will need the latest version of OBS-Studio to be able to record your screen, as prior vesions do not support wayland. Do add the OBS repository to install the latest version (the version in the Ubuntu repositories works only with x-server)

Comment: GIve a try Snap from https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio .

Comment: @Irsu85 No i haven't

Comment: Sometimes you need gpu drivers, try installing those.